# Custom Field Log out Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

When I click to view or edit custom fields; CiviCrm system automatically log out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a domain name problem.

Are you using one of the following :

- subdomains - i.e. http://subdom1.website.org, http://subdom2.website.org
- http / https - i.e. http://website.org, https://website.org
- with and without www. - i.e. http://website.org, http://www.website.org ?

If it is the case, you need to ensure that the main CiviCRM domain (the one that is in `civicrm.settings.php`) is the same that you use during all the civicrm navigation.